# Eloquent Auth Login not working

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to log in providing an email and password. I have tried hashing and not hashing the password myself. I run `dd(Auth::attempt(Input::except('submit')));` and it returns false. Yes the array is correct. Yes that is what's in the database. I followed the `attempt()` to `Illuminate/Auth/Guard.php attempt()` The code for that function is below.

```
 public function attempt(array $credentials = array(), $remember = false, $login = true)
{
    $this->fireAttemptEvent($credentials, $remember, $login);

    $this->lastAttempted = $user = $this->provider->retrieveByCredentials($credentials);

    // If an implementation of UserInterface was returned, we'll ask the provider
    // to validate the user against the given credentials, and if they are in
    // fact valid we'll log the users into the application and return true.
    if ($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials))
    {
        if ($login) $this->login($user, $remember);

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

This function has not be modified at all. `dd($user);` returns the correct information, an instance of User with the attributes pulled from the db. and `dd($credentials);` returns an array of the post information, an email and password.

`dd($this->hasValidCredentials($user, $credentials));` returns `boolean false`.

I have no idea why. Let me know if more info is required. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My password table had a character limit of 20. I'm an idiot. It works now.